# All application passwords lost on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, microsoft-outlook

A couple of days ago I changed my Windows 7 login password. My laptop is on my company's domain, so password changes are done over the internal network.

Since changing the password I noticed that all my saved Chrome passwords are missing. Also Skype, Windows Live, Internet Explorer and Outlook lost their saved passwords. I guess there could be more applications with lost passwords, but I have not opened them yet.

This makes me think that most applications saves their passwords to a general password vault on the Windows system and this vault got somehow corrupted when I changed my domain login password for windows.

Do anyone have any idea of how to fix this and prevent it from happening again?

**EDIT : More Info**

I do development work at the office, so most of the time I bypass the firewall and connect directly to the internet gateway. Now and then I would connect to the company wifi network to do printing and access files on a NAS. So by default my laptop does not connect to the wifi hotspot.

On this occasion to update the password, I had to connect to the wifi. So referring to the comment by OmnipotentEntity below, could this have happened when the system rebooted without a connection to the network as the laptop does not auto connect to the wifi hotspot?

Comment: There is no password vault or keyring. However, it does sound like you lost your userprofile or roaming data.

Comment: Here's another possibility.  I'm not certain now to prevent or fix it with a domained computer.  Your files were Encrypted by the filesystem, which uses a key which is itself encrypted by your password as stored in the SAM hive, if you change your password via a domain setting, the key's encryption might not have been updated.

Comment: Is there anything I can check or do to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent that from happening, I think. When I try to reset local user password in Control Panel, Windows will also warn me about losing network passwords, browser saved passwords, etc.

If you change the password back to the old password, your saved passwords will be back. It seems that all passwords in Windows Vault is encrypted based on your PC login password. When the login password is changed, all your previously saved passwords become undecryptable.

Answer (score 0):

From the book "Windows 7 - the missing manual".

> **Passwords Within Passwords**
>
> The primary password that you or your administrator sets  up in the User Accounts program has two functions.
> You  already know that it lets you log on each day so you can  enter
> your Windows world of desktop clutter, Start-menu  tailoring, Web
> bookmarks, and so on.
>
> But what you may not realize is that it’s also
> the master key  that unlocks all the other passwords associated with
> your  account: the passwords that Internet Explorer memorizes for 
> certain Web sites, the passwords that get you into shared  disks and
> folders on the network, the password that protects  your encrypted
> files, and so on. The simple act of logging  onto your account also
> unlocks all these other secure areas  of your PC life.
>
> But remember that anyone with an Administrator account  can change your password at
> any time. Does that mean that  whoever has an Administrator
> account—your teacher, boss,  or teenager, for example—has full access
> to your private stuff?  After you leave the household, company, or
> school, what’s  to stop an administrator from changing your password, 
> thereby gaining access to your electronic-brokerage account  (courtesy
> of its memorized Internet Explorer password),  and so on?
>
> Fortunately, Microsoft is way ahead of you on this one. The  instant an
> administrator changes somebody else’s password,  Windows wipes out all
> secondary passwords associated with  the account. That administrator
> can log onto your account  and see your everyday files, but he can’t
> see Web sites with  memorized passwords and so on. (The bad news is
> that he’ll  also wipe out your stored passwords for EPS-encrypted
> files,  if any; they’re described on page 679.)
>
> Note that if you change your own password—or if you use  a Password Reset Disk, described in these pages—none of  this applies. Your secondary
> passwords survive intact. It’s  only when somebody else changes your
> password that this  little-known Windows security feature kicks in,
> sanitizing the  account for your protection.

So, it seems like it is intended. However it is strange, because i am the only administrator on my PC and i still lost all my active sessions in Skype, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same effect on a PC not a part of a domain. Just change your password to old value, the one before your last change. (Your domain may have a policy that prevents you from that. Either talk to your sysadmin to switch it off for you, or change password that many times that the controller "forgets" the very old value, then set it - not tested though).